# tomcat - Can't access to project pages error 404

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I'm trying to run my project in Tomcat 7.0.65. The server starts correctly and I can even enter the Tomcat main page, but I can't enter any of my project pages and I get the HTTP 404 error. I tried adding the server again and changing the location from workspace but I still get the same error. Server was working fine a while ago. Any help would be appreciated, I'll leave the image with the error message here.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try restarting your SQL service. If this doesn't work you can go to the properties of the tomcat server and click the "switch location button"